# Is there a trivial way to get non-strict JavaScript codebase to behave in a 'strict' environment?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firefox-addon

I am trying to embed [D3](http://d3js.org) in a [project](https://github.com/abhishekchoudhary/fx-statistics), but keep running into errors, such as 'function does not always return a value' and 'possible use of assignment (=) to test for equality (==)' due to the "use strict" directive in my environment (which, for the curious, is something that happens by default when you develop a Firefox Add-on). Is there an easy fix to this that I am overlooking? I cannot *not* use the strict space, because the dev environment is doing that for me, and apparently, there is nothing I can do to stop it.

Comment: Code is your friend :D

Comment: So.. edit an 8000 line library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never place the "use strict" statement in the global scope, but only in the individual functions:

```
//non strict function doing non strict stuff
function a(){
    return arguments.callee;
}

//strict function calling non strict function
function b() {
    "use strict";
    a();
}

//no error
b();
```

Comment: The environment is involuntary. The Firefox Addon SDK creates it for me.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not familiar with the SDK but in your project you have a file called `main.js` which at its very top says "use strict"

Comment: Its just there for readability. Removing won't remove the restriction, it is built into the SDK.